# Unable to find the path to JSP in struts

Tags: java, struts, wcs

I am working on WCS 6.0 which makes use of the struts framework.
The entry for one of the views(CategoryDisplayView) is defined as the following global forward in the struts config xml

```
<forward className="com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionForward" name="CategoryDisplayView/10001" path="/"/>
```

There is also an action mapping defined for the same which is as under

```
<action path="/CategoryDisplayView" type="com.ibm.commerce.struts.BaseAction">
<set-property property="credentialsAccepted" value="0:P,0:P,0:P,0:P,0:P,0:P,0:P,0:P,0:P,0:P,0:P,0:P,0:P"/>
<set-property property="https" value="10151:1,11301:1,11301:1,13652:1,11351:1,11301:1,12601:1,12601:1"/>
</action>
```

The problem is that I can't find the path to the JSP. Where is wcs getting the path to the JSP for this view? and yes it is finding the correct path, but donno where from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Product and Category pages in Struts do not behave as expected. 

For example, when changing: 
<forward className="com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionForward" name="CategoryDisplayView/10101" path="/"/> 
<forward className="com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionForward" name="ProductDisplayView/10101" path="/"/> 
to: 
<forward className="com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionForward" name="CategoryDisplayView/10101" path="SubCategoriesDisplayDef"/> 
<forward className="com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionForward" name="ProductDisplayView/10101" path="ProductDisplayDef"/> 
There are no resulting changes. The pages continue to render as they did before any configuration changes were made. 
Cause 
The above behaviour happens since WebSphere Commerce uses the DISPCGPREL and DISPENTREL tables to determine the jsp which will render the final view
```

Got it from the technote
**http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.commerce.esupport.doc/html/Customization___Application_Development/swg21328797.html**